# How to handle the speed of downloading images from the url to the app?

Tags: c#

I want to load the image from the URL to the control.But it loads very slowly  and When I clicked on tab 2 and returned to tab 1, the app was stalled.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4Sgr.png)

```
public void ShowImageFromJsonURL()
   {
       string json = (new 
  WebClient()).DownloadString("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/data/en_US/profileicon.json");   
       var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProfileIcon>(json);
       string version = result.Version.ToString();
       string type = result.Type;
       foreach (var item in result.Data)
       {
            string url = "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/" + version + "/img/" + type + "/" + item.Value.Image.Full;
            Image image = new Image()
            {
                 Margin = new Thickness(10, 20, 0, 0),
                 Width = 150,
                 Height = 150,
                 Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute))
             };              
             WrapPanelMain.Children.Add(image);
       }
  }
```

Comment: The download speed is outside you control. It runs however fast the Network does, not faster. The only improovement is that most Browsers will chache pages and images, so they do not need to be downlaoded every time the data is requested.

Comment: Use the async methods of WebClient (or better, of HttpClient) and make your method itself async. Then the program won't "stall". Nothing you're gonna do about the speed of the actual download though

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all your customers having a better internet connection, here are some options within your control:

A) Save the images with lower quality for quicker downloads.

B) Use a real CDN.

C) Cache the images in WPF app startup.

D) Use Async or a background worker to load the images to avoid the application freezing.